# Calculate mapping of exported function location in memory

Tags: debugging, dll, internals, disassembly

I'm debugging an application using disassember (currently VS disassembly window), mainly because I don't have the source code/symbols of DLL I'm debugging.

What I'm trying to find out is which function in the DLL is calling my code. I suspect (and want to check) if it is an exported function.

Using the debugger I can see that the memory location I'm being called from is "0x52CCCF94". So from what I understand, if I can tell where each exported function is being mapped to, I can tell which exported function **might** be calling my code.

So if what I wrote is correct, my question is how can I calculate each exported function "entry point" (that I can see in dependency walker) to its location in the memory.
If what I wrote is a complete nonsense, can someone point me out or set me in the correct direction?

As you can see I'm kinda walking in the dark trying to feel my way through and learn as much as I can on the way.

Thanks a lot for any help!!! :-)